# Possible explanation of sudden spike in memcached get

Tags: heroku, newrelic

Newbie in Newrelic here. I have an API service hosted on Heroku and being monitored at Newrelic.

While I was studying how to use newrelic. I found out my 2 workers are being underutilised with very low RPM and low transaction time. So I decided to cut down to one worker which saves me $36 a month. =]

Shortly after that I received tonnes of logEntries emails stating request timeouts of one of my web dynos. Looking into Newrelic. I found out that one of my actions are being called suspciously high number of times for 2-3 minutes.

The action being `V1::CarsController#Index`, which basically shows a collection of cars.

[image: memcached get]

While I was not sure whether the deletion of one worker dyno has caused memcached to do something, I also suspect that may be someone is trying scrap the data off the database. I am not too sure how to further investigate into the issue. I wonder if I can track down the request IP and see it is the same? or how can I further investigate?

If further information is needed I am happy to provide in Edits!

Thanks

Comment: If traffic to that action has increased in proportion then it is just more requests to your api. If it hasn't then it's more likely to be something else.

Comment: How does cars#index action relate to the memcached get? How come it's contributing to over 98% of the memcached get?

Comment: Maybe it's 98% of the overall traffic - only you can answer those questions

Comment: That 98% means that 98% of all memcache gets are coming from Cars#index transactions. What do you see if you look at Cars#index in the Transactions page in New Relic? There will be a breakdown table showing how many times each "segment" (method, including memcache get) is called and how much time that takes.